# How to set namespace in appengine using go lang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I am able to insert the entities with default namespace but I need to achieve multitenancy. Below is the code i am using to insert the entities and get the entities,but I need to assign namespaces for each entity.So i have followed below link but i am unable to set namespace please help me to fix

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/multitenancy/multitenancy

I found that there are two packages

1."cloud.google.com/go/datastore" - By using this package i am able to insert the entities with out namespace
2."google.golang.org/appengine/datastore" - I found this package from multi tenancy link by google,
I got the clarity that I need to use this package to assign namespaces but I am getting errors while using this package, Please help me to fix this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
)

type user struct {
    UserName string
    Password string
    First    string
    Last     string
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hi")
    http.HandleFunc("/", handle)
    http.Handle("/favicon.ico", http.NotFoundHandler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}

func handle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

    k := datastore.NewKey(ctx, "user", "stringID", 0, nil)
    e := new(user)
    if err := datastore.Get(ctx, k, e); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    old := e.First
    e.First = r.URL.Path

    if _, err := datastore.Put(ctx, k, e); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "old=%q\nnew=%q\n", old, e.First)
}
```

Error :

```
While running the code from local host I am getting below error

E:/GoWork/src/google.golang.org/appengine/internal/api.go:270 +0x186
google.golang.org/appengine.WithContext(0xd60000, 0xc04200c320, 0xc042174000, 0xd60000, 0xc04200c320)
E:/GoWork/src/google.golang.org/appengine/appengine.go:73 +0x46
google.golang.org/appengine.NewContext(0xc042174000, 0x987460, 0xc04216c034)
E:/GoWork/src/google.golang.org/appengine/appengine.go:66 +0x6e
main.handle(0x959da0, 0xc042180000, 0xc042174000)
E:/GoWork/src/simplystdatastore/main.go:27 +0x4a 
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x7e49c8, 0x959da0, 0xc042180000, 0xc042174000)
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1942 +0x4b
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x987460, 0x959da0, 0xc042180000, 0xc042174000)
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2238 +0x137
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc042075550, 0x959da0, 0xc042180000, 0xc042174000)
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2568 +0x99
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0421280a0, 0x95a3a0, 0xc04216e040)
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0x619
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:2668 +0x2d5
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that you've tried out but didn't work?

Comment: The multitenancy document you've linked to uses `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore` but you are using `cloud.google.com/go/datastore`... while these two packages look almost the same they are not so there is a high probability that the reason you can't get namespaces to work is, depending on which way you look at it, because you've been reading the wrong documentation, or because you're using the wrong package.

Comment: Yes I do found same thing
1."cloud.google.com/go/datastore" - By using this package i am able to insert the entities with out namespace
2."google.golang.org/appengine/datastore" - I found this package from multi tenancy link by google,
I got the clarity that I need to use this package to assign namespaces but I am getting errors while using this package

Comment: The stack trace says line `270` of file `appengine/internal/api.go` so go here https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/internal/api.go#L270 and read the comments. **Make sure your local app runs in the `appengine` environment.** Also this new error you are getting is different from the original question so you should create a new question to get more help.

Comment: I am trying to run from local development server (Google Cloud SDK) , I am using **goapp serve** and getting below error
**'goapp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**
Please help me to fix this

Comment: If you've installed the google cloud SDK run the command `gcloud components list` and see if `app-engine-go` is installed, if not, install it with `gcloud components install app-engine-go`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/install

Comment: Yes have installed still getting same issue

Comment: Did you install the `original App Engine SDK for Go` or did you install `Google Cloud SDK` + `gcloud components install app-engine-go`??

Comment: I have installed Google Cloud SDK + gcloud components install app-engine-go

Comment: Ok I'll provide an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344198/goapp-serve-not-working-goapp-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external) in a few minutes.

Comment: Sure,Thank you for quick replays, If needed i will send my screen shots about environment variables etc.,