# goapp serve : not working, 'goapp' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

Cloud any help me,

I am trying to setup local development server from below link

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server

I am getting below errors while using goapp serve command

Error:

**'goapp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: Either you haven't installed it or it's not in your PATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you've installed the `Google Cloud SDK` and then you installed the Go appengine with `gcloud components install app-engine-go` as instructed in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download).

If you read through the instructions you'll find this paragraph:

> Cloud SDK excludes the `appcfg` and `goapp` commands. To continue
>   using those commands, see the steps for downloading and installing the
>   original App Engine SDK.

That means that if you want to use `goapp serve` you need to install the **original App Engine SDK for Go**. Steps for installing it can be found at the bottom of the same [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download) by clicking on the highlighted text *"Or, you can download the original App Engine SDK for Go."*

---

But to run your app locally or eventually deploying to Google Cloud **you don't need the original SDK**. Having `gcloud` installed you also get the `dev_appserver.py` command, you can use this command instead of `goapp serve` to run a local development server like so: `dev_appserver.py /path/to/myapp/app.yml`.

Keep in mind that:

> **dev_appserver.py** does not run in the App Engine flexible environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help
I am trying to use **dev_appserver.py** but it also not running
actually my goworkspace folder is in E Drive

Comment: Thank you so much for your help
I am trying to use **dev_appserver.py** but it also not running
actually google SDK is in **C drive** my goworkspace folder is in **E Drive**
and current project path is e:/GoWorkspace/src/gotest/
gotest folder contains hello.go and app.yaml

How do i mention the path?

when ever i am using **dev_appserver.py** 
I am geeting below code '
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#

"""A convenience wrapper for starting dev_appserver for appengine for python."""

import os
import sys'

Comment: I'm not on Windows so I can't test this but try something like: `python C:/path/to/dev_appserver.py E:/path/to/gotest/app.yml` and have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934675/how-to-execute-python-scripts-in-windows and this http://pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/

Comment: I have installed origianl appengine for Go and installed phython 2.7.14 
and then run the `python -V` command from Command Prompt getting below error
**'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: I have Added environment variables to Python also , It solved the issue
Keep rock Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Here's a nice quide on how to install python on windows https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation